# Install windows, no CD-ROM, locked bios

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, usb, bios

I have a laptop that is locked with a BIOS password I don't know, and the computer need a fresh install of windows due to performance issues.

I can't boot from CD-ROM because it does not have one, and I can't boot from USB, SD or ethernet since I can't access the bios.

This is what I was thinking:
I have a SATA to USB Adapter. I can unplug the harddrive from my laptop and format it via another computer. Then I'll download a Repair Disk and place it on the empty harddrive, connect it to the laptop and boot. From there I can open a CMD prompt and navigate to a windows installation on a USB stick.

My only question is; Can I just copy the content from a repair disk directly to the harddrive, and then it will boot?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to copy Windows to disk and install from it, but they are quite complicated and I never had any luck doing it. I think the easiest way is to borrow an external CD-ROM and you should be able to boot from it.

Comment: I can't access any USB's at boot, so a external CD-ROM wouldn't do much. The only thing I need, is to be able to boot a windows cmd prompt. From there everything should be fine.

Comment: @theusual than I suggest trying this http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-CLEAN-Install-Windows-8-directly-from-Hard-/ but I wasn't able to work it on my PC, but it was in special circumstances (dual boot) so it may work for you